# System process listener in python

Tags: python

Is there any way to notify when the system process started, terminated or completed.

I am searching kind of listener that listen events of the system, such as process start, stop etc.

Comment: what is your OS? What do you want to do with the events (provide context).

Answer (score 0):

You can launch `ps` command, parse its output and get info about running processes. I haven't found better way still. If you're on unix of cause.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there is [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2018/Detecting-Windows-NT-2K-process-execution). It might be possible to use it via `ctypes`.

[`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) provides an example `top` implementation in Python. It uses polling to enumerate running processes.